# A facade root has not been set.in Facade.php (line 218) Laravel 5.4. Problem with Route?

Tags: php, laravel-5, frameworks

I moved my site to Laravel on a local server, after solving several migration problems 5.3 to 5.4. But one problem remained unresolved when requesting the address http: //localhost:8000/rpc

[error with Facade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJB2c.jpg)

I think the problem is in Route. My web.php

```
Route::any('/rpc', ['middleware'=>'cors', function() {
    return ExtDirect::provide();
}]);

Route::options('/rpc', ['middleware'=>'cors', function() {
    return ExtDirect::provide();
}]);
```

Can someone provide me with advice on this?